# Getting java.lang.NumberFormatException in the code

Tags: java, bufferedreader, numberformatexception

Code :

I have `TriangleSummer` class which has class variable

```
static BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

My main function is

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int noOfTestCases = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    for(int i=0;i<noOfTestCases;i++){
        int noOfEntries = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        System.out.println(computeMaxSum(noOfEntries));
    }
}
```

Relevant part of my `computeMaxSum()` method is

```
public static int computeMaxSum(int noOfEntries) throws IOException {

    int[][] triangle = new int[noOfEntries][noOfEntries];

    for(int j=0;j<noOfEntries;j++){
        int k=0;
        for(String str : reader.readLine().split(" ")){
            triangle[j][k] = Integer.parseInt(str);
            k++;
        }
    }
  //further logic nothing to do with I/O
 }
```

and finally stack trace is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at Matrices.TriangleSummer.main(TriangleSummer.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

for the input

```
2
3
1
2 1
1 2 3
4 
1 
1 2 
4 1 2
2 3 1 1
```

So I am getting NumberFormatException while reading line number 6 i.e value 4 at line

```
int noOfEntries = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
```

. And I am completely clueless so as to why?

Comment: _"java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 "_ You have an extra space, trim your String. And the doc mention: _"The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 "
```

It seems there is space at end. Do a `trim()` before passing to `Integer.parseInt(str);`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space from string "4 ", using `String#trim()`

```
It returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted
```

Code snippet -

```
for(String str : reader.readLine().split(" ")){
     triangle[j][k] = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
     k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this one will remove your spaces

```
int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
```